# django plural for templates

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I get django to realize that the singular form of `countries` is `country` and not `countrie`

Comment: Django? Or a specific part of it?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#pluralize), if you have a template variable called num_countries, you could just write something like:

```
countr{{ num_countries|pluralize:"y,ies" }}
```

Comment: Yes, look at the note here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#pluralize

Comment: But this is not usable when translating strings.

Answer (score 13):

I know this question is specifically asked for templates, but for anyone (just like me) stumbling upon this question while searching for the solution in 'Python-side' Django

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import pluralize

def pluralize_countries(countries):
    return 'countr{}'.format(pluralize(countries, 'y,ies')
```

The pluralize function looks at the first parameter to see if it's plural or not. Let's assume the first parameter is always an array of some kind. So:

```
if len(countries) > 1:
    # PLURAL!
else:
    # SINGLE!
```

Than, it looks at the second parameter to see what to do if the first parameter is single or plural.
A rough sketch of the pluralize code looks like this:

```
def pluralize(arr, options):
    split_options = options.split(',')
    if len(arr) > 1:
        return split_options[1]
    else:
        return split_options[0]
```

I know the pluralization is slightly more complex. But in a nutshell, this is what it does.