# How do I make Django add the plural of category as categories instead of categorys

Tags: django

In my Django project I have a category tables however the plural is showing at categorys is there a way to force categories instead?

I tried renaming the table but that did not work

I also tried manually changing this by changing my model however I receive the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django plural for templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185363/django-plural-for-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    your_field_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
```

This will set the model name to Category and Categories in django admin according to the records dynamically.

However, if you still need to perform raw sql query (if you need to), then use the actual model name (class name) in query.

Comment: This works great thankyou!